# How to remove function implementation from a python file?

Tags: python

I am designing python assignments for a class. I define functions, write docstrings and then I implement them. Afterward, I'd like to remove all my implementations of the functions and replace only the code (not the doc-strings, function names, and arguments) with a `raise NotImplementedError`.

Is there any tool (e.g. IDE) which removes all the code for me automatically, so that I don't have to replace the implemented function by myself? I was thinking about writing a small script, but I thought I might ask here before I do this ...

If anyone has written something similar or knows of a quick way how to this, I would appreciate this a lot.

Here's a minimal example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
test.py

def add(a,b):
"""
Adds two numbers
"""
 return a+b

def multiply(a,b):
"""
Multiplies two numbers
"""
 return a*b
```

should become in an automated fashion (and of course for much larger files):

```
test.py

def add(a,b):
"""
Adds two numbers
"""
   raise NotImplementedEror

def multiply(a,b):
"""
Multiplies two numbers
"""
   raise NotImplementedEror
```

Comment: Can you show a small example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi,
I've just edited the question.

Comment: Why not use a decorator that raises `NotImplemented` unless you give it some global boolean like `flag = False`

Comment: Otherwise I'm not sure why you're trying to do this

Comment: This is not a programming question. As I said I'm developping homework. I'm writing files where students help to implement up to 40-50 functions. I simply want an easy way, how all the fuction-implementation can be deleted so that I don't have to do this by hand.

Comment: my bad, I read `class` as in an object

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a tool to do specifically this, but Python provides great AST manipulation tools within its own standard library via the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module. You'll need a third party module to "unparse" the result after transformation back into regular Python code, and after a quick search I found [this one](https://astunparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems to do the trick, although there do seem to be many others.

Here's a bit of sample code to get you in the right direction. Obviously, you'll need to tweak this to get the exact behavior you want, especially if you want to provide classes instead of just top-level functions (as I've written nothing to handle that use case). But with a bit of Python knowledge, it should be possible to automate.

Also, this is Python 3 (which, as of the start of 2020, is the *only* supported Python version). If you're still on Python 2, it may require some modifications.

```
import ast
import astunparse

# Read our file using the built-in Python AST module.
with open('filename.py') as f:
    data = ast.parse(f.read(), 'filename.py')

# Loop through all declarations.
for decl in data.body:
    # Only modify functions
    if isinstance(decl, ast.FunctionDef):
        # The docstring is the first statement of the body. So we don't
        # want to change it. Instead, replace the rest of the body with
        # our pre-built "raise" call. Note that I figured out what "raise"
        # looked like in AST form by running
        #
        # ast.dump(ast.parse("raise NotImplementedError()"))
        #
        decl.body[1:] = [ast.Raise(ast.Call(ast.Name('NotImplementedError'), [], []), None)]

# Use astunparse to pretty print the result as Python code.
print(astunparse.unparse(data))
```

It's definitely possible to automate, if you're willing to take the time to do it. If you're planning to do this for several assignments, or even over several semesters, you may consider making a script for it. But if you're just doing it once, it may be more worth your time to just do it by hand.